# Images in vendor directory not precompiling

Tags: assets, rails-4-2-1

I am using the DataTables library in my Rails 4.2.1 application. I have manually included all of the assets that are required including 1 js file, 1 css file, and 3 images. The js and css are properly precompiling but the images are not.

Currently the three images are located in `vendor/assets/images/<name>.png`. They are not precompiling (which after some research is intentional in rails 4.0+) and after attempting all of the fixes I could find on SO I still cannot get these images properly loaded by the asset pipeline. I have tried the following fixes to no avail.

**Attempted fixes**

- Move images to `app/assets/images`
- Add `config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)` to `config/application.rb`
- Add `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "images")` to `config/application.rb`

**Errors**

The error messages thrown by DataTables js are the following:

- GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/assets/images/sort_both.png 404 (Not Found)
- GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/assets/images/sort_asc.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The first image should be accessible at http://localhost:3000/assets/sort_both.png. If that works, then there are probably incorrect hard-coded paths to the images in the css file.

Comment: That was exactly it thank you. I'm still learning about the asset pipeline and where they become accessible.